# Placement of "during"

Tags: placement

I was taught that in English the "when part" of a sentence goes at the beginning of the sentence.

However, I feel that when using "during X", it is preferable to include it at the end of a sentence, rather than at the beginning, which goes against the general rule.

Take this random example:

> During an illness, the body heals itself.

I feel that this second version of the example, with the "during X" clause placed at the end, is more idiomatic:

> The body heals itself during an illness.

Where do you think should the "during X" clause be placed? Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, there's no rule that "when" goes at the beginning of a sentence. It's *more common* to do it that way, but putting it at the end is still correct.

Comment: Not only is it correct, but it's common. I'm writing this example after the first sentence.

Answer (score 4):

It largely depends on how you want to order your emphasis.

Both are grammatical and idiomatic.

There is certainly not a hard and fast rule that 'during' needs to be placed first. Indeed there are few such rules in English about word order.

Just say it the way you feel it sounds best.